# find max ID with the largest number of occurrence of an attribute

Tags: mysql, sql

Making some exercises I don't know how to make this query

Having this 2 tables

StudentTable(**IDstudent**,....)

Exam(**IDexam**,...,student,...,result)

where

- student in exam references IDstudent in student
- resutl has a boolean value

example

```
 StudentTable
 IDstudent
 S0001
 S0002
 S0003


 EXAM
 IDexam     student    result
  1          S0001      true
  2          S0002      true
  3          S0002      true
  4          S0003      false
```

The query have to show the ID of student with the largest number of true in exam and the number

In the case of example
         S0002     2

I've tried

```
  SELECT 
      student, count(1)
  FROM
       Exam  E join StudentTable  S on E.student=S.id_student
  WHERE result='true'
  GROUP by student
```

What I have is

```
    S0001    1
    S0002    2
```

but I don't know how take the max

- How can I do?

This is the link to the schema http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/895ea/8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
  SELECT 
    student, count(1)
  FROM
       Exam  E join StudentTable  S on E.student=S.id_student
  WHERE result='true'
  GROUP by student 
  ORDER by 2 DESC
  LIMIT 0,1
```

**LIMIT (N,N)** clause in MySQL is equivalent to **TOP (N)** in T-SQL

Comment: this will only return one value of the total result. what if there are students that has the same number of `true` result?

Answer (score 3):

One thing I like this query is that it supports duplicate student having the highest number of `true` answer.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    StudentTable a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  Student
            FROM    Exam
            WHERE   result = 'true'
            GROUP   BY Student
            HAVING  COUNT(*) =
                    (
                        SELECT  COUNT(*) count
                        FROM    Exam
                        WHERE   result = 'true'
                        GROUP   BY Student
                        ORDER   BY count DESC
                        LIMIT   1
                    )
        ) b ON a.IDStudent = b.Student
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1823a/3)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (having duplicate highest number of `true` result)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b0fa8/2)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  student, count(result) AS number
FROM
   Exam  E join StudentTable  S on E.student=S.id_student
WHERE 
   result='true'
GROUP BY 
   student 
HAVING 
   number = (SELECT COUNT(result) FROM exam WHERE result='true' GROUP BY student ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Link to [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/895ea/31)